# Selecting files from multiple folders with a certain extension

Tags: python, directory, glob

So consider this as the Folder structure below:

Images

- -1.jpg
- Yellow

  - yellow1.jpg
  - yellow2.jpg
  - yellow1.csv
- Blue

  - blue1.jpg
- Orange
- Purple

  - purple1.jpg
  - purple2.jpg
  - puprple.csv

Now my agenda is to take all the jpegs from the Images master directory which are there in separate folders.

I thought I can use glob as
input_dir=r'../../../../Images'
files=glob.glob(input_dir+"/**/*.jpg")
but this only yields output with the last file
like files=files=[''../../../../Images/purple2.jpg']
but I want the files as
['../../../../Images/yellow1.jpg','../../../../Images/yellow2.jpg','../../../../Images/blue1.jpg','../../../../Images/purple1.jpg','../../../../Images/purple2.jpg']

I need to have all the files, can someone help me rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `pathlib`.

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path("your_source_folder")
files = [f for f in p.rglob('*.jpg') if f.is_file()]
```

This will recursively go through your folder structure, select all jpeg files and return a list of Path objects for all found files.